# PayPal - Adaptive Payment: how do I know PaymentId on Success page?

Tags: c#, paypal, sdk

I use [PayPal Adaptive Payments SDK for .NET](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-dotnet/tree/v2.12.117) and I try to implement simple payment.
There is the following flow:

- Create simple payment (PayRequest) and get payment KEY (here I specify returnUrl as http://bla-bla-bla.com?invoiceId=567)
- Redirect user to PayPal with url
  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=[KEY]
- after user logged in to PayPal and confirm payment - PayPal redirects me to
  success page http://bla-bla-bla.com?invoiceId=567

The problem is there is no way to add some customer data to PayRequest object. And I do not know how to get transactionId on success page, because we initialize PayRequest.ReturnUrl before transaction created.
How can I get transactionId on success page?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in your **return url** you can add your query string data as transactionId, then paypal will return to this url, so you can easily grab your transactionId

Comment: I can not add transacton Id to return URL because return URL is a property of PayRequest, and I do not know transaction Id before Pay request executed.